# systemclt services and ssh

Tags: github, ssh, systemd, systemctl

I have a simple bash script that makes a call to a git repository on github (/home/user/simple_git.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change to the Git repoistory
cd /home/user/git/a_git_repo

remote=$(
    git ls-remote -h origin master |
    awk '{print $1}'
)

local=$(
    git rev-parse HEAD
)

printf "Local : %s\nRemote: %s\n" $local $remote
```

It gives the following output:

```
Local : a10dc1d7d30ed67ed1e514a3c1ffc5a824cea14b
Remote: a10dc1d7d30ed67ed1e514a3c1ffc5a824cea14b
```

git authentication is done via ssh keys - the following is my my .bashrc

```
# ssh
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

The script runs just fine as user as well as with sudo (by preserving the user environment) ie.

```
~/.simple_git.sh
or
sudo -E ~/simple_git.sh
```

However, I've still not yet found a way to run the script as a service (/etc/systemd/user/simple_git.service or /etc/systemd/system/simple_git.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=TestScript

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/simple_git.sh
```

I've tried running the systemctl command with the --user option as well as modifying visudo to include the line

```
Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

but to no avail. Everytime I check the status of the job:

```
Feb 21 23:16:00 alarmpi systemd[484]: Started TestScript.
Feb 21 23:16:01 alarmpi simple_git.sh[15255]: Permission denied (publickey).
Feb 21 23:16:01 alarmpi simple_git.sh[15255]: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Feb 21 23:16:01 alarmpi simple_git.sh[15255]: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
Feb 21 23:16:01 alarmpi simple_git.sh[15255]: and the repository exists.
Feb 21 23:16:01 alarmpi simple_git.sh[15255]: Local : a10dc1d7d30ed67ed1e514a3c1ffc5a824cea14b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd is not running the service with your environment variables from your session. I would recommend you to

- Use git using `https`, which will not require authentication (instead of `ssh`)
- Create an unprotected "deploy key", which will be in standard location (`~alarmpi/.ssh/id_rsa`), which will get picked up by `git` automatically without `ssh-agent`.

Comment: I found the command `systemctl --user import-environment` in the [Arch systemd/User wiki page] (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User). Having applied this it works. We use two factor authentication with our github repository which is why I didn't think https would work. What is the benefit of using an unprotected deploy key? It doesn't sound particularly secure but I may be missing the point and not having to use the ssh-agent is a bonus I guess.

Answer (score 0):

At this time (working practise policy) it was not possible to use https to connect to github. While the idea of an unprotected deploy-key is useful I ended up using systemctl --user import-environment ([wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)) to mange the issue at this time.